# How to multiply length of list by a number

Tags: python

I want to multiply the length of a `list` named `cost_ten` by a number.
e.g:

```
cost_ten = ["itemone", "itemtwo", "itemthree"]

def costten_function():
    (len(cost_ten))
```

Here I want to multiply the length of `cost_ten` by a number and print that number.

Comment: Whats wrong with `len(cost_ten) * x`? Where `x` is some numeric value.

Comment: Hi @Graykat, please tell us what you've tried so far. This is pretty fundamental to the language, and the fact that you've already found `len(...)` means that you have found the [python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/), or a post that is very similar to what you're looking for. I recommend you look around and search a little more, and you'll find a surprising amount if information already here.

Comment: Perhaps you could share the exact error you are getting @Graykat, because the code as presented has some syntax errors. You also should look into the `return` keyword.

Comment: nvm The first comment worked its fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that multiplies the length of a list passed as param times another param num that will at as your multiplier.

```
cost_ten = ["itemone", "itemtwo", "itemthree"]
def costten_function(cost_ten, num):
    return len(cost_ten) * num

print(costten_function(cost_ten, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

is very easy only get list length with `len` function and use multiply operator like this

```py
cost_ten = ["itemone", "itemtwo", "itemthree"]
c_len = len(cost_ten)
print("value=", (c_len * your_value))
```

the asterisk `*` is the multiply operator

Answer (score 0):

**==> simple**

```
List= len(["itemone", "itemtwo", "itemthree"]) 
print("The length of list is: ", List * desired_value)
```

**desired_value can be any number**

Answer (score 0):

```
cost_ten = ["itemone", "itemtwo", "itemthree"]
//Change this as per your requirement
num = 9 
def costten_function():
     print("Length of list multipled by some number",len(cost_ten)*num)
```

Replace num with your desired number